# ASP.NET Windows Autentication with custom login

Tags: c#, asp.net

im looking for how to connect Active Directory and windows authentication (maybe digest) in a custom login.

I just found with forms authentication...

any suggest?

Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by *custom login*?

Comment: login buttom, when click insert user and pass

Comment: Just to make sure: you *can't* use Windows Authentication and jump the `user/pass` step, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use LDAP

here is an example of how it works [LDAP Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18742/Simple-Active-Directory-Authentication-Using-LDAP)